# RFLP Pedigree question

Tags: genetics, homework, human-genetics, quantitative-genetics

A relatively frequent, completely penetrant recessive disease variety of mutations in the gene. The gene has been recently cloned. Analysis of the region flanking the gene reveals that the population has at three (3) RFLP (this is a type of DNA marker; they are not SNPs so have much larger sizes) alleles in this region. The sizes of the RFLP alleles are 7, 10 or 13 kb in length. Shown here are two small pedigrees of families in which affected individuals are shaded in black. The size of the RFLP alleles each individual carries is shown below the pedigree. enter image description here

[image]

Question: If the male child from the left pedigree marries the female child from the right pedigree, What is the probability their child will be a carrier?

I said that there isn't enough information to tell since the parents genotypes are unknown.

Answer (score 1):

> I said that there isn't enough information to tell since the parents genotypes are unknown.

It seems like you are misreading the diagrams since you say the parent's genotypes are unknown.  All 8 individuals in the two pedigrees have the same information given for each, appearing in the eight columns directly beneath the eight individual's symbols.